# NPM Spaces in Path causes Google Drive errors Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, google-drive-api

So I'm currently experiencing some issues with Google Drive and NPM. I am using the new Google Drive on Windows (if I remember correctly, used to be called Google Filestream).

The issue basically involves the fact that when I do `npm install` in a Node.JS directory, it tells me that the `<PROJECT DIRECTORY>/node_modules` folder doesn't exist. Using the same project files and package.json in my local Downloads folder worked absolutely fine and installed everything like it was supposed to.

The full error is as below:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\Coding\1. Node\1. Discord.JS\SleepBot\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\Coding\1. Node\1. Discord.JS\SleepBot\node_modules'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stent\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-13T17_06_01_171Z-debug.log
```

*If the log file is relevant, please let me know and I will upload it.*

And my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "sleepbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A custom bot to fix the brat's sleep schedule",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sleepbot"
  ],
  "author": "Stentorian",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ascii-table": "^0.0.9",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ms": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Comment: can you try when you copy the project to a file path that doesn't have spaces in the folder names? It's been a while since I did Node work on Windows, but I recall sometimes have issues with that.

Comment: I think that is what the problem appears to be, but I cannot change that Google Drive displays has the folder "My Drive" and I use Google Drive to keep a safe backup of everything code wise. The `G:` drive is the virtual drive that Google Drive mounts to in order to function.

Comment: Get thee to https://github.com/ ! ;)

Comment: You might try editing your question and title to call out "spaces in path" and "Windows" to solicit responses from developers who have likely encountered the same issue.

Comment: I use GitHub, however, I don't instantly upload all changes to Git and mainly use it for production basis because I have (way too many times) made changes on master and not dev and messing everything up. I am trying to use it more often, however, I also have personal projects that I want to keep completely local.

Comment: What command are you running exactly? Have you tried multiple times? I tried to reproduce your directory in Google Drive with the command `npm install --prefix "G:\My Drive\Coding\1. Node\1. Discord.JS\SleepBot\node_modules" random_package` and it did work, however, in CMD I got your error message once but the next attempt worked. On PowerShell it worked right away but there were some write errors. The package was installed normally in the end though and it works even if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: I am literally running `npm install` and I have tried the whole running it multiple times but there's always an error and most of the time, it's the same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whilst not a direct solution the problem, it is one that I have come to start using as I cannot find a fix to this problem.

I am now running my projects locally from my Documents folder, using Git/GitHub for saving changes (making use of branches), and a script that periodically compresses my coding folder (excluding node_modules) and saves it to the G:/ drive (Google Drive).

Comment: Looks like you got a better answer, though not a solution on https://linustechtips.com/topic/1417879-npm-and-google-drive-issue/

I tried, as a workaround, creating a symbolic link on another partition where I could have a path without spaces. then I tried running the npm install in an elevated command prompt (a.k.a. the Windows version of `su root`) ... still failed. I think, as stated elsewhere, it's Google, not the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. I don't know the fix to it but if I encounter it when running some npm commands I just move the whole project to a local directory, run the command and move it back. It is not ideal but works.

Comment: That is the solution I had to do until I just moved to keeping the whole directory in my documents folder and just zipping it and uploading it to Google drive every so often and using git for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution! I haven't had a problem since I implemented this.

If you go to the Google Drive settings you can change your syncing options to "Mirror files" (this will download your whole google drive to your computer). It will ask you to select a folder. I suggest changing the default "My Drive" in C:\Users\"yourUserNameHere"\My Drive to "MyDrive" or "My_Drive". Removing the space may spare you the possible problems you may run into. Alternatively, you can select any folder you like but avoiding any spaces in the full path is still recommended.

Assuming you haven't changed any other settings you will still have G:\My Drive but if you navigate to that folder it will just redirect you to the path above.

This should already solve the issue, but if that is not the case just make sure that you are running the commands from the local drive and not G:\...

Answer (score 0):

To make NPM work on Google Drive, you only need to ensure that the folder where you want to use it is not located within G:\ (the default Google Drive unit) but in a separate folder, and then instruct Google Drive to add that folder.

Comment: Hi, please add supporting information, explaining how this should work. Thank you